# Convert txt file into JSON in python

Tags: python, json, text-files

I have a txt file which have the format shown below and the Key strings are not in quotes. How can I convert into a JSON using python?

```
name {
  first_name: "random"
}
addresses {
  location {
    locality: "India"
    street_address: "xyz"
    postal_code: "300092"
    full_address: "street 1 , abc,India"
  }
}
projects {
  url: "www.githib.com"
}
```

Comment: Hint : Use `json` module.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid

Comment: @TerryA I think the OP realizes that the text file isn't JSON. They want to know how to convert it to JSON.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM The json module won't handle that data without some pre-processing.

Comment: @Rakesh That dupe target isn't relevant here. The OP's data isn't actually JSON.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the clarification i just edited that in my question.And yes guys the Key values are not in quotes and hence i needed them to be converted into JSON. Any help on how to do that will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nish I've re-opened your question, and posted some code. Generally, it's expected that you post your own attempt at writing code for your problem. I guess in this case you didn't know where to start, but even then you should write _something_ relevant and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way in the standard library to convert that data format to JSON, so we need to write a parser. However, since the data format is fairly simple that's not hard to do. We can use the standard `csv` module to read the data. The `csv.reader` will handle the details of parsing spaces and quoted strings correctly. A quoted string will be treated as a single token, tokens consisting of a single word may be quoted but they don't need to be.

The `csv.reader` normally gets its data from an open file, but it's quite versatile, and will also read its data from a list of strings. This is convenient while testing since we can embed our input data into the script.

We parse the data into a nested dictionary. A simple way to keep track of the nesting is to use a stack, and we can use a plain list as our stack.

The code below assumes that input lines can be one of three forms:

1. Plain data. The line consists of a key - value pair, separated by at least one space.
2. A new subobject. The line starts with a key and ends in an open brace `{`.
3. The end of the current subobject. The line contains a single close brace `}`

```
import csv
import json

raw = '''\
name {
  first_name: "random"
}
addresses {
  location {
    locality: "India"
    street_address: "xyz"
    postal_code: "300092"
    full_address: "street 1 , abc,India"
  }
}
projects {
  url: "www.githib.com"
}
'''.splitlines()

# A stack to hold the parsed objects
stack = [{}]

reader = csv.reader(raw, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
for row in reader:
    #print(row)
    key = row[0]
    if key == '}':
        # The end of the current object
        stack.pop()
        continue
    val = row[-1]
    if val == '{':
        # A new subobject
        stack[-1][key] = d = {}
        stack.append(d)
    else:
        # A line of plain data
        stack[-1][key] = val

# Convert to JSON
out = json.dumps(stack[0], indent=4)
print(out)
```

**output**

```
{
    "name": {
        "first_name:": "random"
    },
    "addresses": {
        "location": {
            "locality:": "India",
            "street_address:": "xyz",
            "postal_code:": "300092",
            "full_address:": "street 1 , abc,India"
        }
    },
    "projects": {
        "url:": "www.githib.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data as,

```
{
    'addresses': {
        'location': {
            'full_address': 'street 1 , abc,India',
            'locality': 'India',
            'postal_code': '300092',
            'street_address': 'xyz'
        }
    },
    'name': {
        'first_name': 'random'
    },
    'projects': {
        'url': 'www.githib.com'
    }
}
```

Use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to convert dict to json

```
In [16]: import json

In [17]: data
Out[17]:
{'addresses': {'location': {'full_address': 'street 1 , abc,India',
   'locality': 'India',
   'postal_code': '300092',
   'street_address': 'xyz'}},
 'name': {'first_name': 'random'},
 'projects': {'url': 'www.githib.com'}}

In [18]: json.dumps(data)
Out[18]: '{"name": {"first_name": "random"}, "projects": {"url": "www.githib.com"}, "addresses": {"location": {"postal_code": "300092", "full_address": "street 1 , abc,India", "street_address": "xyz", "locality": "India"}}}'

In [19]:
```

Comment: But the OP's data file doesn't look like your input data. In particular, the key strings aren't quoted.